# How can I use Selenium 4.7.2 (Python) on an old Firefox version (Firefox 47)?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a Selenium project which is working on a recent version of Firefox. Now I need to make it work on Firefox 47. What would be the best way to do that? Will it work if I use an older version of geckodriver?

Answer (score 0):

It depends mostly on geckodriver version. So, if you can get geckodriver version compatible to the old Firefox version you want to use - this should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately even older versions of geckodriver do not explicitely support Firefox 47.

Comment: It should be not just old version, but version supporting that specific version of Firefox